# Is there a difference in laptop RAM?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavilion DV9750 laptop and I want to to replace my current memory from 2X1GiB to 2X2GiB.

Now I've seen a couple of websites, but most have a really model-specific memory?

What kind of RAM do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://crucial.com as well as http://newegg.com both have tools to pick compatible RAM for your computer.

Answer (score 3):

You need pretty much any ram/memory of the correct specification (e.g. speed/type) that will fit in the laptop.

The are generally 2 sorts of memory - Guaranteed compatible - these comes from the manufacturer directly and is simply "extra/better" of what came with the machine, and the next is aftermarket/OEM kits.

Some websites have configurators and guides to help you, but generally, it is the same stuff.

So, if your laptop takes 1GB SODIMM DDR2 800 speed make sure you get a SODIMM DDR2 800 2GB.

... If you haven't already, you may want to upgrade to a x64 bit operating system if you are not already running one in order to take advantage of 4GB.